# Toastr Success message showing every page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, toastr

I am using codeigniter 3 framework, where i use toastr notification. When i save a page i get success message from toastr, the same message is repeating if i reload or navigate to another page. I don't have any idea why its happening. Please help me out to get the issue fixed.

Controller:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', DELETE_MSG)
```

Script:

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "100",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "3500",
  "extendedTimeOut": "60000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')){ ?>
    toastr.success("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>");
<?php }else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){  ?>
    toastr.error("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>");
<?php }else if($this->session->flashdata('warning')){  ?>
    toastr.warning("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warning'); ?>");
<?php }else if($this->session->flashdata('info')){  ?>
    toastr.info("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('info'); ?>");
<?php } ?>
```

I tried to change the configuration of the toastr but no luck.

Comment: This isn't an issue with Toastr since it only shows a toast if you tell it to. Are you really setting the flashdata in your _view_ though? Please add more context.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but could it have anything to do with setting the message in the *session*? Do you ever remove it from the session?

Comment: @mykaf - When you save it as "flashdata", it will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared. CodeIgniter handles that for you.

Comment: Sorry, not in view. Its in controller

Comment: @M.Eriksson i have set the flash dat in controller only. Please view the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a CodeIgniter expert, but you said you have this code in a view:

```php
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', DELETE_MSG)
```

First of all, it doesn't seem like the best place to add this type of code.

Second, if it's indeed in a view, maybe it's been called on every request before you call `flashdata` ?

Make sure your logic is correct and that you are not calling `set_flashdata` on every request.

Comment: Sorry, not in view. Its in controller

Comment: Flash message set in the controller only. Please view the updated question.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you further. If the notification is showing on every request, chances are you are setting the flash data on every request. First, check your generated HTML: is the ` toastr.success` call being generated for every request? If yes, then you are certainly setting the flash data somewhere during the request.

Answer (score 0):

Set flash message in your controller after saving or making a request.

Comment: Flash message set in the controller only. Please view the updated question.

Comment: in what function did you add your set flash data? Is it after you transact or at the page load?